# Как заменить значения нескольких столбцов в датафрейме

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных, nan

Необходимо заменить значения NaN в нескольких столбцах датафрейма, в каждом столбце на свое. Перепробовала множество разных способов, ничего не получается.

Датафрейм stud:

```
famsize | Pstatus | paid  |Fedu
 NaN    |  A      | no    | 4.0
 GT3    |  NaN    | NaN   | 2.0
 LE3    |   T     |  yes  | NaN
```

В famsize NaN надо заменить на GT3, Pstatus - на Т, paid - на no, Fedu - на 2.0

Пробовала следующее:

1. [image: функция]

   `stud.apply(fix_columns)`

- выдает TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
  Если пробовать применить функцию к одному столбцу:

  `stud.famsize.apply(fix_columns)`
- ничего не происходит

2. `stud.famsize = stud.famsize.replace('NaN', 'GT3', inplace=True) display (stud.famsize)`

- все значения заменяются на None. Если без inplace=True - ничего не происходит.

3. `stud.famsize.map({'NaN':'GT3'}).fillna(stud.famsize)`

- ничего не происходит

Как правильно написать код? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: попробуйте: def fix_columns(stud): for x in stud.addres: x.replace('NaN', 'U')

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Общее правило для всех методов Pandas - если вы используете параметр `inplace=True` то изменяется сам объект и ничего не возвращается (вернее возвращается `None`). Если этот параметр не указать или явно задать `inplace=False`, то создается копия объекта, изменяется данная копия и возвращается в качестве результата.

Поэтому надо делать либо так:

```
df.method_name(..., inplace=True)
```

либо так:

```
res = df.method_name(...)
```

---

Воспользуйтесь методом `DataFrame.fillna()`:

```
res = df.fillna({"famsize":"GT3", "Pstatus":"T", "paid":"no", "Fedu": 2.0})
```

результат:

```
In [50]: res
Out[50]:
  famsize Pstatus paid  Fedu
0     GT3       A   no   4.0
1     GT3       T   no   2.0
2     LE3       T  yes   2.0
```